# Metal cannon wall thickness

Tags: weapons, engineering

I'm planning on making a cannon with a bore of anywhere from 2 inches to 3/4 inches.

How thick should the wall be?

Comment: Welcome to the site user62348, please take the [tour] and read up in our help centre about how we work: [ask] You'll discover when you browse the [help] centre that your question doesn't fit on worldbuilding.se, I'd suggest that you consider [physics.se] and take their tour and look at their help centre to see how to approach the issue. You would need to specify a metal, lead is a great deal softer than brass or steel for example, and a barking dog type cannon is a great deal smaller and slimmer than a "Tsar Cannon".

Comment: What kind of cannon? Medieval? Early modern? Modern? Naval? Anti-aircraft? What metal? Bronze? Steel? What propellan? Black powder? Modern smokeless powder? What projectiles? For a quick feel, look at the pictures of a [50 mm cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_cm_Pak_38) and a [57 mm cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_mm_anti-tank_gun_M1943_(ZiS-2)).

Comment: A muzzle loading cannon, just to mess with, and a steel pipe, I cannot weld, assnd it would be black powder

Comment: It would also likely fire stone or metal balls

Comment: @Agrajag Please note that Physics SE would probably close this an an engineering question.

Comment: @StephenG Didn't think to look, that should be [engineering.se] then.

Comment: If you want to "mess" with it, you will probably mess up. If it works, the bullet will come down **somewhere**. It it doesn't work, the gun will burst and and throw metal splinters around.

Comment: @user62348, yesterday I gave a rather harsh reply, and I still believe it is the right one. But do you realize that in most parts of the world, adults **can** shoot firearms for sports/recreation? If you are in one of those countries, find a shooting range and ask if it is possible to fire a gun under the supervision of an instructor. That will cost some money, but much less than a lost hand ...

Answer (score 3):

If this is the real world and not a *fictional* setting, don't do that at home. Seriously. The difference between a cannon and a pipe bomb is how thick the walls are, and how well the end caps fit.

- Depending on where you live, you might break the law by doing gunsmith work without proper certification, too.
- In the US, the cannon might be classified as a [destructive device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructive_device).

Where do you think the missing parts of this barrel went?
[image]

That guy got lucky when his rifle malfunctioned. (graphic content)

> [image]

This was war rather than an accident. (graphic content)

> [image]

Comment: People have continued to express concern about this content; there's really no reason to have it visible. To be honest, I'm not sure I see the *benefit* of it at all. It's rather gratuitous, and doesn't do anything productive when it comes to actually answering the question. I'll leave it here for now, under spoilers, but . . . still. Please consider removing it, period. There are other ways to emphasize to the OP that this is a crappy/dangerous idea.

Comment: @HDE226868, it seems to me that the OP is unintentionally trying to blow himself up. I feel morally compelled to do something. If I could read the access logs of this site with a halfway meaningful IP, I'd probably call his local police department. As it is, I can only warn. I want to do that in the strongest possible terms. *Don't do that at home. You will be mutilated.*